# How to see from where a public method is called in Eclipse using Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, method-call

I am working on a Java project in Eclipse. Sometimes when I do refactoring I would like to see from what other classes a public method is called.

There is a primitive way to do this, that I am using now. I can comment out the method and see in what classes there is an error in Eclipse. Is there any better way to do this in Eclipse? E.g. by selecting the method signature and run a command by a key-shortcut?

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+G` shows you from where the method is being called whereas `Ctrl+Alt+H` shows calls from the method in the workspace.

Comment: @Prince ah that's what I've been looking for for ages.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Click on the method name, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the Call Hierarchy view.

Comment: @AdamParkin: I would imagine that bringing up the context menu will show you the shortcuts available.

Comment: Actually figured it out: it's under Navigate -> Call Hierarchy, or the shortcut key is CTRL+option+H

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+G` shows you from where the method is being called whereas `Ctrl+Alt+H` shows calls from the method in the workspace.

Comment: @Prince: Ctrl+Alt+H does either - although I typically use it to show calls *to* the method rather than calls *from* the method.

Comment: @Prince : `Ctrl+Alt+H` gives me the calls only from current file which is open, i want to know all the calls being made to a function in a project (let's say a directory), cscope does the job but is there any way to do this in eclipse? (I am using C/C++ (CDT) for my project.

Comment: @DarthSpeedious: Well if you're using C/C++, why would you expect the answer to a *Java* question to work? CDT and JDT are very different - Ctrl-Alt-H works fine showing all calls in Java...

Comment: Thanks Ctrl+Alt+H work fine in eclipse, i have tested for java

Answer (score 12):

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> for "Find References in Workspace"

Answer (score 9):

`Search > References > Workspace`

This will build a tree of results in the search view of every reference to the method. The hotkey is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do is make it throw an exception (public void test() throws Exception{})  that way eclipse would put errors at every place that calls the method (as long as its not in a try/catch block or it throws an Exception too), this way will only work if you want to search classes in your project.

Comment: This is a horrible way to do something that is already built into eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Cntrl + Shift + G

This shows where the call is made along with the hierarchy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 4.23 (Feb. 2022, 12 years later) does add to this view with:

> ### [Show implementations of callee](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.23/jdt.php#show-implementations-of-callee)
>
> The **call hierarchy view** can now show implementing methods as potential callee methods when viewing callees.
>
> [image: Callee call hierarchy -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.23/images/callee_on_implementations.png]
>
> This behavior can be controlled from following preference
>
> [image: Call hierarchy preference -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.23/images/callee_preference.png]